# How to search an array of coordinates in Java?

Tags: java, arrays, search, coordinates

I have an array in Java. Each entry of array is a pair of numbers (x and y coordinates).

Technically, an example of my array is:

setOfPoints = {(1,2), (3,4), (5,6), (1,9), (7,4)}

How can I search that list and check whether (3,4) is part of that set?

Ideally, I would like to do a Java function isCoordinateInSet((3,4), setOfPoints). I would also like to avoid using for loops that could potentially increase the time of operation. I am thinking of using Java Maps fpr this task. What do you think?

I am not following the Java syntax above, but I described it as so, to better explain what I want to do.

I would appreciate your input.

Thank you.

Comment: When you say "each entry is a pair of numbers" - do you mean you've created your own class? Using a map is fine, but that removes ordering - and at that point it's a map, not an array. Would a set be good enough, in fact? Using Java code would be *much* clearer in terms of explaining what you've got. You should also make your requirements clear.

Comment: @JonSkeet how do you find a solution using multihashmap?

Comment: @BlueBullet: I think having a separate class for a pair of coordinates would be considerably cleaner. It sounds like a meaningful concept in the OP's problem domain.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
public class Point{

    private int x,y;

    public Point(int x, int y) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }

    public int getX() {
        return x;
    }

    public void setX(int x) {
        this.x = x;
    }

    public int getY() {
        return y;
    }

    public void setY(int y) {
        this.y = y;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;

        Point point = (Point) o;

        if (x != point.x) return false;
        if (y != point.y) return false;

        return true;
    }

    @Override 
    public int hashCode() {
        int result = x;
        result = 31 * result + y;
        return result;
    }
}
```

---

```
    Set<Point> points = new HashSet<>();
    points.add(new Point(3,4));
    points.add(new Point(5,6));
    points.add(new Point(1,2));
    points.add(new Point(3,5));

    System.out.println(points.contains(new Point(3,4)));
    System.out.println(points.contains(new Point(1,2)));
    System.out.println(points.contains(new Point(2,4)));
```

Comment: This piece of beautiful code worked like amazing charm! Thank you assylias and user1121883!

Answer (score 3):

You could create a class Coordinate that holds the (x,y) pair and override its equals/hashcode methods to make two instances having the same x and y be equal.

Then you create one Coordinate instance per pair in your array and add them to a `Set<Coordinate>`, for example a `HashSet`.

Then you `isCoordinateInSet` is simply a call to `set.contains(new Coordinate(3,4));`.

Answer (score 0):

Apache commons library has a class named `MultiHashMap` which is in `org.apache.commons.collections` package. I think you can use [MultiHashMap](http://commons.apache.org/collections/apidocs/org/apache/commons/collections/MultiHashMap.html) for searching a particular coordinate.

```
MultiMap mhm = new MultiHashMap();
mhm.put(3,5);
mhm.put(3,4);
mhm.put(5,6);
mhm.put(3,8);
List list = (List) mhm.get(3);
```

`list` will contain 5,4 and 8. After you find *x-coordinate* value, you will search for *y-coordinate* in this list.